# How can I reduce the size in array environment?

Tags: equations, amsmath

My code is

```
\[
    D_{k+1}(x_{k+1}) = \min_{\begin{array}{c}
    \text{all } x_k \text{ such that}\\
    p_{{x_k}{x_{k+1}}} > 0
    \end{array}}
    \left[ D_k(x_k)-\ln\left(p_{{x_{k-1}}{x_k}}
    r\left(z_k; x_{k-1}, x_k\right)\right) \right]
\]
```

[image: equation]

However, I want to make `all x_k such that p_{{x_k}{x_{k+1}} > 0` smaller.

How can I reduce the size of that part?

Comment: You can use `\resizebox` or `\scalebox` probably from the `graphicx` package. I would also suggest `\forall x_k|p_{{x_k}{x_{k+1}}}`

Comment: @Mico Yes, you're right.  Sorry!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use the `\substack` macro of the `amsmath` package. Compared with the `array` method used in your example, the material in the argument of `\substack` is automatically set in `\scriptstyle`. Also, do abbreviate "such that" to "s.t.".

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath} % for \text and \substack macros
\begin{document} 
\[
    D_{k+1}(x_{k+1}) = \min_{%
    \substack{\text{all $x_k$ s.t.} \\[0.25ex] 
              p_{x_k x_{k+1}} > 0}}
    \bigl[ D_k(x_k)-\ln\bigl(p_{x_{k-1} x_k}
    r(z_k; x_{k-1}, x_k)\bigr) \bigr]
\]
\end{document}
```

Comment: Can you let me know make it a bit smaller?

Comment: @Danny_Kim - Please clarify what you mean by "make it a bit smaller". Honestly, I would *not* make "it" any smaller unless you're willing to distribute magnifying glasses along with your document. :-) If you do wish to make the substack material take up less space, the place to start would be the unwieldy double-subscript term `p_{x_{k-1} x_k}`. Any chance it can be written more concisely?

Comment: @Mico: maybe using in  the substack `\mathclap{p_{x_k x_{k+1}} > 0}`?

Comment: I decided to satisfy this result!. Thank you very much. The more I use the latex, the more I am feeling this language is not easy.